# Data member of some class

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

### Simplified problem

Given

```
class Foo f where
    frobnicate :: f -> Float
```

how could I allow any `instance` of `Foo` in

```
 data Bar = Bar { <here> }
```

?

### Actual problem

Given

```
-- Typically lightweight geometric objects, e.g. spheres
class Shape s where
    intersect :: (RealFrac t, Floating t, Ord t, Shape s)
              => Ray t -> s t -> Maybe (DifferentialGeometry t)
```

and

```
-- Primitives contain higher level informations, like material properties
class Primitive p where
    intersect :: (RealFrac t, Floating t, Ord t, Primitive p)
              => Ray t -> p t -> Maybe (Intersection t)
```

Note the only difference in the signatures of `Primitive.intersect` and `Shape.intersect` lies in the return type.

Now I would like to add a wrapper which basically transforms any `Shape` into a `Primitive`.

I would think it works roughly like this:

```
data ShapeWrapperPrimitive t = ShapeWrapperPrimitive {
                                  shape :: (Shape s) => s t
                               }
```

or in other words, I would like to add an arbitrary `shape` member, which is of the `Shape` class.

However, this gives me `Illegal polymorphic or qualified type`.

Comment: Why not `data ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t = ...` and `instance (Shape s) => Primitive (ShapeWrapperPrimitive s) where ...` instead?

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Oh had you just written out the `...` ... :) See my own answer. I am really used to bad error messages (C++), but Haskell adds a new dimension to it. Will one get used to it?

Comment: GHC's error messages tend to be terse but informative, once you learn to decipher what they mean (note that its suggested "solutions" are often ridiculous). So yeah, I guess that qualifies as "getting used to it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if your simplified problem is really a simplification of the actual problem. The **answer to the simplified problem** is:

If the only thing you can do with an unknown type that is an instance of class `Foo` is to turn it into a `Float`, then you can just as well store the `Float`.

So you'd use

```
data Bar = Bar Float
```

However, if I understand your **actual problem** correctly, then you want to wrap a type that is an instance of class `Shape` and thereby turn it into an instance of class `Primitive`. For this, I'd define

```
newtype ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t = ShapeWrapperPrimitive (s t)
```

and then say

```
instance Shape s => Primitive (ShapeWrapperPrimitive s) where
  intersect = ... -- fill in definition here
```

Comment: Accepting, because even though `newtype` does not apply (I want to add more data to `ShapeWrapperPrimitive`) it was your syntax-non-error that uncovered my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to the question you asked, but it may be helpful. If you're creating a list with both `Shape`s and `Primitive`s, then you need a wrapper type, as described by thoferon. But if you're not, then maybe you don't really need a wrapper type.

You said "Note the only difference in the signatures of `Primitive.intersect` and `Shape.intersect` lies in the return type." You can represent that relationship using type families, as shown below. This gives you a type family called `Thing`. The result type of `intersect` can be different for each type that is an instance of `Thing`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class Thing t where
  type Result t
  intersect :: Ray t -> s t -> Maybe (Result t)

-- Made-up type definitions just to get things to compile
data Shape s t = Shape s t
data Primitive p t = Primitive p t
type Ray t = (Double, t)
type DifferentialGeometry t = [t]
type Intersection t = [t]

-- Typically lightweight geometric objects, e.g. spheres
instance Thing (Shape s t) where
  type Result (Shape s t) = DifferentialGeometry t
  intersect a b = undefined

-- Primitives contain higher level informations, like material properties
instance Thing (Primitive p t) where
  type Result (Primitive p t) = Intersection t
  intersect a b = undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two solutions to this kind of problems :

1) Use the language extension `ExistentialQuantification`. So you can write :

```
data Blah = forall a. Num a => Blah a
```

2) Move the constraint to your functions, like

```
data Blah a = Blah a

f :: (Num a) => Blah a -> a
f = undefined
```

or your instances :

```
instance (Num a) => Foo (Blah a) where
  -- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Even though I accepted another answer, I'll post this for future visitors.</sub>

---

My problem was more or less a what could be considered a typo. At some point, I had

```
23:  data ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t = ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t
24:  
25:  instance (Shape s) => Primitive (ShapeWrapperPrimitive s) where
26:     intersect _ _ = Nothing

--- >> line 25: Expecting one more argument to `s'
```

which let me to a path of confusion and torment. Notice how it points me to line 25. The accepted answer uncovered my mistake: Instead of

```
data ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t = ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t
```

I was in need of

```
data ShapeWrapperPrimitive s t = ShapeWrapperPrimitive (s t)
```

The first would have added an `s` and a `t` as a members, whereas I really wanted an `s t`; adding the parens solved my problem.